# How to use unslider on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, unslider

I have been trying to use unslider (jQuery) on a project of my own. Despite following the instructions on the https://idiot.github.io/unslider/ website, I can't seem to get things to work.

Would anyone be kind enough to take a look at my code and give some feedback as regards to what can be going wrong here?

Thanks!

--

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Testing unslider</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/unslider-master/dist/css/unslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/unslider-master/dist/css/unslider-dots.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="my-slider">
    <ul>
        <li>My slide</li>
        <li>Another slide</li>
        <li>My last slide</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/unslider-master/src/js/unslider.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.my-slider').unslider();
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Open the developer console. What errors do you see? Are all the files (CSS, JavaScript) being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running this locally (you're not serving this through a web server). If that's the case, here's what you need to fix:

First, You need to get rid of the forward slash in your unslider asset URL's. Using the forward slash means that the browser will look for the file relative to the root of the URL which is not what you want. Instead, you want the browser to look for the file in the current directory.

Second, use `https` for the protocol in the jQuery asset URL to fetch it directly from the web. `\\` is useful because it allows the URL to be protocol independent when making the request from a server that may or may not use `https`. However, when you're fetching files from your file system you'll end up with a URL like `file://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js` which will fail because jQuery is not on your machine.

Here's a working version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing unslider</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="unslider-master/dist/css/unslider.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="unslider-master/dist/css/unslider-dots.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="my-slider">
        <ul>
            <li>My slide</li>
            <li>Another slide</li>
            <li>My last slide</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="unslider-master/src/js/unslider.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.my-slider').unslider();
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```